# uiview on top of uitablecell

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview

I have a custom table view with a custom table view cell. 
I have a uiview with three buttons. How can I set that when a row is selected the uiview will popup over the cell? Basically I want a popover controller. Should the uiview be inside by table view controller?
I'm targeting iphone and cannot use people's project.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether your popover view fits entirely within the cell.

If so, when you build the cell, add the popover view and mark it `hidden`.  Then, when the delegate is told that the cell has been selected, change `hidden` to `NO` (you could even play with the `alpha` and wrap that inside `[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]` to have it fade in).

If not, then you'll want to have the popover view ready ahead of time, and add it to the window directly when the cell is selected.  You'll want to use the `frame` of the cell and the `[cell convertRect:to:]` method to position your view appropriately.  You will also want to make sure that you add a "background" `UIView` to ensure that stray touches can't reach the `UITableView` underneath.